# How to use python to split lines of a txt file into a list with variables

Tags: python-3.x

This is the example of two lines from the **sample.txt** file

```
2021-06-12 16:40:49,225 INFO:URL: http://localhost:8000/page

2021-06-14 16:56:46,488 INFO:URL: http://localhost:8000/gpage
```

Result for each line:

```
['2021-06-14','16:56:46','488','INFO','URL','http://localhost:8000/gpage']
```

How can we get this result without using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

first of all replace text "INFO:URL:" with "INFO URL " then replace "," with space and split text by space

```
a="2021-06-14 16:56:46,488 INFO:URL: http://localhost:8000/gpage"
aa=a.replace("INFO:URL:","INFO URL ").replace(","," ").split()
print(aa)
```

it gives

```
 ['2021-06-14', '16:56:46', '488', 'INFO', 'URL', 'http://localhost:8000/gpage']
```